# Python mock patch a function called by another function

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, mocking, patch

```
def f1():
    return 10, True

def f2():
    num, stat = f1()
    return 2*num, stat
```

How do I use python's mock library to patch `f1()` and return a custom result so I could test `f2()`?

**Edited:**
Is there something wrong with my test? This doesn't seem to be working, all the tests failed with AssertionError

```
from foo.bar import f2
from mock import patch

class MyTest(TestCase):

    def test_f2_1(self):
        with patch('project.module.f1') as some_func:
            some_func.return_value = (20, False)
            num, stat = f2()
            self.assertEqual((num, stat), (40, False))

   @patch('project.module.f1')
   def test_f2_2(self, some_func):
       some_func.return_value = (20, False)
       num, stat = f2()
       self.assertEqual((num, stat), (40, False))
```

Answer (score 60, accepted):

First example suggests that f1() and f2() defined in the same module.
Hence the following should work:

```
from foo.bar import f2
from unittest.mock import patch

class MyTest(TestCase):

    @patch('foo.bar.f1')
    def test_f2_2(self, some_func):
        some_func.return_value = (20, False)
        num, stat = f2()
        self.assertEqual((num, stat), (40, False))
```

Patch is on the same as import: `@patch('foo.bar.f1')`

Here is a good answer on the issue:

http://bhfsteve.blogspot.nl/2012/06/patching-tip-using-mocks-in-python-unit.html

Comment: Thanks for recommending the http://bhfsteve.blogspot.nl link about patching and import styles. That solved one of my problems.

Comment: How would this be different if `f1` and `f2` were in different modules?

Answer (score 31):

Assuming that you're using this [mock](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/index.html) libary:

```
def f1():
    return 10, True

def f2():
    num, stat = f1()
    return 2*num, stat

import mock

print f2()   # Unchanged f1 -> prints (20, True)

with mock.patch('__main__.f1') as MockClass:       # replace f1 with MockClass 
    MockClass.return_value = (30, True)     # Change the return value

    print f2()     # f2 with changed f1 -> prints (60, True)
```

If your code is divided into modules you would probably need to replace `__main__.f1` with the path to your module/function.

Comment: Would it make any difference if f1() accepts args? E.g: f1(arg)

Comment: The mocking function can be called with any number of arguments, it'll always return the `return_value`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Secator. I have updated my question with a test case and it doesn't seem to be passing. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The test failed with AssertionError