# patch my function to random randint function

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I have a function to generate `sms_token`. It must not duplicate with the existing one in the database. However, the space of token might not so big enough then the collision of the newer one might happen.

`Python 3.7.0`

```py
from random import randint

from multy_herr.user_profiles.models import UserProfile


def rand_six():
    """
    Must find the `sms_token` which no `UserProfile`
    :return:
    """
    tmp = ""
    for i in range(6):
        tmp += str(randint(0, 9))
    if 0 == UserProfile.objects.filter(sms_token=tmp).count():
        return tmp
    else:
        return rand_six()
```

Therefore I wants to make `side_effect` of `randint` to return me the deterministic values by this order `123456, 123456, 111222`

With given values. I will be able to test `else` logic in my `rand_six`

I had tried this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10277397/python-mock-patch-a-function-within-another-function), but does not work. `rand_six()` still return me the original function not the fake one I made.

```py
from unittest.mock import patch
from multy_herr.users.utils import rand_six

    @patch('random.randint')
    def test_rand_six(self, some_func):
        """
        Suppose it generates the duplicated `sms_token`
        :return:
        """
        some_func.return_value = '123456'
        assert '123456' == rand_six()
```

**Problem:**

It does not patch the behavior of `random.randint`

**Question:**
How can I put my fake generated list to my `randint`?

Comment: You have to patch `randint` in the module where it is imported: e.g. `@patch('your_module.randint')`

Comment: Please wait a moment. I also trying another easier approach to test this case.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to `Klaus D.` for his comment. I have to stick with `module`.

1. Use `import random` and `random.randint(0, 9)`

```py
import random

from multy_herr.user_profiles.models import UserProfile


def rand_six():
    """
    Must find the `sms_token` which no `UserProfile`
    :return:
    """
    tmp = ""
    for i in range(6):
        tmp += str(random.randint(0, 9))
    if 0 == UserProfile.objects.filter(sms_token=tmp).count():
        return tmp
    else:
        return rand_six()
```

2. Use `global` in order to get my defined value with given condition. And a bit cheat with my own question. Since I want 2 answers the same, but not last one.

```py
    def _rand111(self, a, b):
        global idx
        if idx in range(12):
            idx += 1
            return 1
        else:
            return 2

    def test_mock_randint(self):
        """
        Test mock the behaviour of `random.randint`
        :return:
        """

        with mock.patch('random.randint', self._rand111):
            assert '111111' == rand_six()
            assert '111111' == rand_six()
            assert '222222' == rand_six()
```